# Query never completes when calling the AVG function in a subquery and cursor block while using a window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, window-functions

I'm querying trading candlesticks in my database.
Firstly I'm fetching rows that have been specifically filtered, once I've got these rows I want to find the 19 previous candles for each candle and apply an `AVG` function.

The only issue is that `AVG` function in the cursor block is taking an indefinite time to complete (it never completed even after hours).

What could it be?

```
DECLARE @candles_table TABLE
(
     [CandleStickBitmexSqlId] BIGINT INDEX IX0 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] DATETIME INDEX IX1 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick] FLOAT INDEX IX2 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[Symbol] NVARCHAR(450)
    ,[Open] FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,[High] FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,[Low] FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,[Close] FLOAT NOT NULL INDEX IX3 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[Trades] BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,[Volume] BIGINT 
    ,[Vwap] FLOAT 
    ,[LastSize] FLOAT 
    ,[Turnover] BIGINT
    ,[HomeNotional] FLOAT 
    ,[ForeignNotional] FLOAT 
    ,[IsReplacingMissingCandle] BIT
    ,[IsCandleCompleted] BIT
    ,[IsCandleGeneratedByLiveTrade] BIT
    ,[CandleStickTimeFrame] NVARCHAR(450)
    ,[CounterBatch] INT
    ,[UpperBollinger] FLOAT
    ,[LowerBollinger] FLOAT
    ,[BB_UPPER_PRECENT] FLOAT
    ,[BB_LOWER_PRECENT] FLOAT
    ,[BB_MA] FLOAT
    ,[CountPointsCalculated] INT
)

DECLARE @candles_table_resp TABLE
(
     [CandleStickBitmexSqlId] BIGINT INDEX IX0 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] DATETIME INDEX IX1 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick] FLOAT INDEX IX2 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[Symbol] NVARCHAR(450)
    ,[Open] FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,[High] FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,[Low] FLOAT NOT NULL
    ,[Close] FLOAT NOT NULL INDEX IX3 NONCLUSTERED
    ,[Trades] BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,[Volume] BIGINT 
    ,[Vwap] FLOAT 
    ,[LastSize] FLOAT 
    ,[Turnover] BIGINT
    ,[HomeNotional] FLOAT 
    ,[ForeignNotional] FLOAT 
    ,[IsReplacingMissingCandle] BIT
    ,[IsCandleCompleted] BIT
    ,[IsCandleGeneratedByLiveTrade] BIT
    ,[CandleStickTimeFrame] NVARCHAR(450)
    ,[CounterBatch] INT
    ,[UpperBollinger] FLOAT
    ,[LowerBollinger] FLOAT
    ,[BB_UPPER_PRECENT] FLOAT
    ,[BB_LOWER_PRECENT] FLOAT
    ,[BB_MA] FLOAT
    ,[CountPointsCalculated] INT
)


INSERT INTO @candles_table
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
     MyT2.[CandleStickBitmexSqlId] 
    ,MyT2.[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] 
    ,MyT2.[TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick] 
    ,MyT2.[Symbol] 
    ,MyT2.[Open] 
    ,MyT2.[High] 
    ,MyT2.[Low] 
    ,MyT2.[Close] 
    ,MyT2.[Trades]
    ,MyT2.[Volume]
    ,MyT2.[Vwap] 
    ,MyT2.[LastSize] 
    ,MyT2.[Turnover] 
    ,MyT2.[HomeNotional] 
    ,MyT2.[ForeignNotional] 
    ,MyT2.[IsReplacingMissingCandle] 
    ,MyT2.[IsCandleCompleted] 
    ,MyT2.[IsCandleGeneratedByLiveTrade] 
    ,MyT2.[CandleStickTimeFrame] 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MyT2.[CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC) AS [CounterBatch] 
    ,MyT2.[UpperBollinger] 
    ,MyT2.[LowerBollinger]
    ,CAST(((([High]*100)/MyT2.[UpperBollinger] )-100) AS decimal(10,4)) AS BB_UPPER_PRECENT
    ,CAST(((([Low]*100*-1)/MyT2.[LowerBollinger])+100) AS decimal(10,4)) AS BB_LOWER_PRECENT 
    ,MyT2.[BB_MA]
    ,MyT2.[CountPointsCalculated]

    FROM (
        SELECT
             [CandleStickBitmexSqlId] 
            ,[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] 
            ,[TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick] 
            ,[Symbol] 
            ,[Open] 
            ,[High] 
            ,[Low] 
            ,[Close] 
            ,[Trades]
            ,[Volume]
            ,[Vwap] 
            ,[LastSize] 
            ,[Turnover] 
            ,[HomeNotional] 
            ,[ForeignNotional] 
            ,[IsReplacingMissingCandle] 
            ,[IsCandleCompleted] 
            ,[IsCandleGeneratedByLiveTrade] 
            ,[CandleStickTimeFrame] 

            ,NULL AS [CounterBatch]

            ,AVG([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) + (STDEV([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) * 2) AS UpperBollinger
            ,AVG([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) - (STDEV([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) * 2) AS LowerBollinger 
            ,NULL AS [BB_UPPER_PRECENT] 
            ,NULL AS [BB_LOWER_PRECENT] 
            ,AVG([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) AS [BB_MA] 
            ,COUNT([Close]) OVER(ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) AS [CountPointsCalculated]


        FROM [bitmex].[CandleStickBitmexSql]
        WHERE CandleStickTimeFrame like 'min5' 
        AND  
        '2021-03-16 19:00:00.000' <= TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick 
        AND 
        TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick <= '2021-04-01 17:15:00.000'

    ) AS MyT2
    WHERE 
    [CountPointsCalculated] >= 20 
    AND 
    ( 
    [LOW] < [LowerBollinger] 
    )       
) AS MyT3
ORDER BY MyT3.[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] DESC




SELECT * FROM @candles_table_resp
SELECT * FROM @candles_table


DECLARE @c_CandleStickBitmexSqlId BIGINT 
DECLARE @c_TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick DATETIME 
DECLARE @c_TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_Symbol NVARCHAR(450)
DECLARE @c_Open FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_High FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_Low FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_Close FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_Trades BIGINT 
DECLARE @c_Volume BIGINT 
DECLARE @c_Vwap FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_LastSize FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_Turnover BIGINT
DECLARE @c_HomeNotional FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_ForeignNotional FLOAT 
DECLARE @c_IsReplacingMissingCandle BIT
DECLARE @c_IsCandleCompleted BIT
DECLARE @c_IsCandleGeneratedByLiveTrade BIT
DECLARE @c_CandleStickTimeFrame NVARCHAR(450)
DECLARE @c_CounterBatch INT
DECLARE @c_UpperBollinger FLOAT
DECLARE @c_LowerBollinger FLOAT
DECLARE @c_BB_UPPER_PRECENT FLOAT
DECLARE @c_BB_LOWER_PRECENT FLOAT
DECLARE @c_BB_MA FLOAT
DECLARE @c_CountPointsCalculated INT

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
     [CandleStickBitmexSqlId] 
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] 
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick] 
    ,[Symbol] 
    ,[Close] 
    ,[CandleStickTimeFrame] 
    ,[CounterBatch] 
FROM @candles_table
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor 
INTO 
 @c_CandleStickBitmexSqlId
,@c_TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick
,@c_TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick
,@c_Symbol
,@c_Close
,@c_CandleStickTimeFrame   
,@c_CounterBatch
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    

      --INSERT INTO @candles_table_resp
      SELECT TOP (19) 
        *
        ,@c_CounterBatch AS [CounterBatch]
        --********** THE FOLLOWING AVG FUNCTIONS ARE BLOCKING/SLOWING THE QUERY ***************** 
        ,AVG(csbitmex.[Close]) OVER (ORDER BY csbitmex.[CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) + (STDEV(csbitmex.[Close]) OVER (ORDER BY csbitmex.[CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) * 2) AS [UpperBollinger]
        ,AVG([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) - (STDEV([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [CandleStickTimeFrame] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 19 FOLLOWING) * 2) AS [LowerBollinger] 
        --,NULL AS [UpperBollinger] 
        --,NULL AS [LowerBollinger] 
        ,NULL AS [BB_UPPER_PRECENT] 
        ,NULL AS [BB_LOWER_PRECENT] 
        ,NULL AS [BB_MA] 
        ,NULL AS [CountPointsCalculated] 
      FROM [bitmex].[CandleStickBitmexSql] AS csbitmex
      WHERE 
      TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick < @c_TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick
      AND 
      [Symbol] LIKE 'XBTUSD' 
      AND 
      [CandleStickTimeFrame] LIKE 'min5' 
      ORDER BY TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick DESC 



    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor 
    INTO 
     @c_CandleStickBitmexSqlId
    ,@c_TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick
    ,@c_TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick
    ,@c_Symbol
    ,@c_Close
    ,@c_CandleStickTimeFrame  
    ,@c_CounterBatch
END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor





SELECT
     [CandleStickBitmexSqlId]
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick] 
    ,[TimestampSnapShotUnixEpochCandleStick] 
    ,[Symbol] 
    ,[Open] 
    ,[High] 
    ,[Low] 
    ,[Close] 
    ,[Trades] 
    ,[Volume] 
    ,[Vwap] 
    ,[LastSize] 
    ,[Turnover] 
    ,[HomeNotional] 
    ,[ForeignNotional] 
    ,[IsReplacingMissingCandle] 
    ,[IsCandleCompleted] 
    ,[IsCandleGeneratedByLiveTrade] 
    ,[CandleStickTimeFrame] 
    ,[CounterBatch] 
    ,[UpperBollinger] 
    ,[LowerBollinger] 
    ,[BB_UPPER_PRECENT] 
    ,[BB_LOWER_PRECENT] 
    ,[BB_MA] 
    ,[CountPointsCalculated] 
FROM @candles_table_resp AS tcr
ORDER BY 
tcr.CounterBatch,
tcr.TimestampSnapShotUtcCandleStick DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Begs the question: why are you using a cursor, can this not be done set-based? I also don't get why you have `19 following` in a query that starts `select top (3)`

Comment: @Charlieface updated top 19, but this is not the issue blocking the query

Comment: I didn't say it was. The cursor almost certainly is though. This whole procedure could probably be done in a single `select`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I know cursors are slow and that there are in general other better options. Honestly I've been thinking about it in the last 3 days but nothing popped in my mind.

Comment: Just join the cursor query with the `select top` query, either use a rownumbering solution to get the top 19 per group, or use `cross apply`. [There are hundreds of examples of this online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @Charlieface besides the commands you mentioned please point out some other topics that I might read. Thank you